# How to get maven assembly plugin to copy artifact?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a Maven assembly script that copies resources to build our app. I need to copy some war files from separate, external projects into a /webapps directory in the output. Can't seem to find the magic commands to do it.

I tried adding a dependencySet to the assembly with `<include com.mygroup:mywarfile>`. This works if I add 'mywarfile' as a war dependency in the project with a scope of compile or runtime. Unfortunately, my project produces a war, and the maven-war-plugin includes the external mywarfile as an overlay, which I don't want.

If I set the scope of the external war dependency to provided or test, the assembly fails with the warning:

[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter:
 'com.mygroup:mywarfile'

All I want to do is have the assembly copy an artifact from my local repo to the assembly output. How to do it without messing up other parts of the project?

Answer (score 2):

The maven-assembly-plugin is not intended for copying. The better way to copy dependencies is the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin) which can copy dependencies etc. If you a talking about deployment into Tomcat etc. than you should take a deeper look into [carg2-maven-plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Maven2+plugin) or the [tomcat-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html) which seemed to be more appropriate for that task.

Comment: Um, copying is *primary* purpose of the maven assembly plugin. FileSet, DependencySets and the rest of it are intended for the sole purpose of copying parts of the app into the final release. Having to use a separate maven-dependency-plugin defeats the purpose of the assembly plugin. Plus, it doesn't work if your assembly output is to a zip file.

Comment: Sorry to say but according to the name the maven-assembly-plugin assembles artifacts and/or files into an archive but is not intended to copy artifacts from one location to an other. If you like to copy artifacts from within a build (multi-module or from a repository) the dependency plugin is exactly what you neeed.

Comment: @user237815: The assembly plugin can only work with files already available in the project.  It is not intended for adding unavailable content so IMHO the dependency plugin is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you could try using the `exclude` feature of `overlay` configuration of `maven war plugin` to exclude contents of the dependant war file from being included in your war project. Modified snippet from the [Overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) documentation,

```
...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <overlays>
            <overlay>
              <groupId>com.example.projects</groupId>
              <artifactId>warToBeExcluded</artifactId>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </overlay>
          </overlays>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
...
```

Comment: This does work, and it was our workaround before I posted the question. It's kind of a hack, though.