# With the maven assembly plugin, how can I copy an artifact to a directory?

Tags: java, maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have an assembly descriptor that copies project modules, dependencies and even files to my release folder, and this is fine. One of the files I'd like to copy, however, is in fact an artifact identifiable with maven coordinates.

**The question:** Is it possible to specify a file in an assembly `fileSet` or `files` stanza by using maven coordinates (groupId:artifactId:version)? And if not, what would be an equivalent way of achieving this?

Finally, the artifact I want to copy is *not* a dependency of my project, so I cannot use filtered `dependencySet`. This also distinguishes this question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123862/how-to-get-maven-assembly-plugin-to-copy-artifact)

Comment: Not a direct answer, but a different way to think about it: your project does depend on this artifact, otherwise you'd have no need to copy it.

Comment: @parsifal what I'm trying to copy is org.apache.felix.main. It's needed to start the OSGi container, but the bundles in it depend on org.osgi.core (the interfaces) only. In doing so, I can change the actual OSGi container implementation. The point is, because it's not a dependency declared in the pom, it cannot be picked up by the dependency plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the dependecy plugin and the get goal.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thanks! Shame the assembly plugin doesn't support it natively

Answer (score 1):

I would use the maven-dependency-plugin (in particular the `copy` goal) to fetch the external artifact and then use the assembly plugin to package it.

Here is the [documentation of the plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks! I think the solution proposed by @hami is a bit faster in that it's a single step.